# How to selectively log call stack

Tags: java, android, stack, logcat

I'm pulling my hair out trying to understand android objects' lifecycles and debugging my code. After having read hundreds of questions on lifecycles of `Activity`s, `Fragment`s and `Service`s, I've come to the conclusion that confusion is the natural state of affairs for most Android developers in this area, which comforts me to some degree.

I have wrapped android's `Log.x()` functions in my version, `LOG.x()` which accepts additional arguments so I can filter what is logged based on flags, but I would like to extend it further so I can examine real-time call graphs.

At the moment, I must have hundreds of `LOG.x()` calls at the beginning of methods. This, with the flags, has helped me a great deal. But it still falls a bit short:

It would be nice if I could see a **real-time hierarchical tree/list of (filtered) calls.**

I'm amazed I haven't seen anything like this! **Are there any tools which do it?**

If not, what would be a good way of writing this? I think calling `Log.x()` is now falling short, it's obviously not meant for this. I was thinking of writing an eclipse plugin, and using `System.out`'s `println()` calls or similar to get data to it. But this would become an enormous amount of work.

Then there's the matter of actually determining which methods called which methods and so on.

Any advice would be great
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is such a thing as printStackTrace(), and it can be used virtually everywhere:

```
 public static void printStack() {
    Throwable throw = new Throwable();
    throw.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Also, I think what you're thinking of is a non-interactive debugger. There wasn't a need for one, since we have the interactive ones.